# How to get the order (rank) of each item in a list?

Tags: netlogo

For example, a list [5,1,6,7,9]
I want to get the order of each item: [1 0 2 3 4]
This is easy for python, but how to do that in netlogo?

p.s I am hurrying for my homework. If you know the solution, please reply soon!
Many thanks!

Comment: Not easy - it's not really the sort of thing I can ever imagine anyone wanting to do in NetLogo. Are you sure you have interpreted the question correctly? Some combination of actually sorting it then using `position` to find each element iteratively might work.

Comment: What have you tried? Where exactly are you getting stuck when you try to solve this yourself?

Comment: Welcome to SO; please have a look at the thread [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest) (tl;dr: **never**).

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of doing someone's homework for them, here is how I would handle it.  First realize that if we sort the list, the indices of the resulting list will be the "ranks" we want in our final output.  You can get the index of a number from a list using [the `position` primitive](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#position).  Then we can easily use [the `map` primitive](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#map) to replace each value in the original list with the "rank" from the sorted array.

Step-by-step example:

```
to step-by-step-ranking
  let items [5 1 6 7 9]
  let sorted sort items 
  ; sorted is now [1 5 6 7 9]
  show sorted

  ; so the `position` of the number 5 in `sorted` is index `1`
  show position 5 sorted 
  ; and the `position` of the number 5 in `sorted` is index `0`
  show position 1 sorted
  ; and so on for the other items, `position` gives our rank

  ; so we just need to do `position n sorted` for each number in order
  ; which is what `map` will do for us
  ; `map` to `position` from `sorted` for each number in `items`
  let ranked map [ n -> position n sorted ] items   
  show ranked ; outputs [1 0 2 3 4]
end
```

And if you want a more general purpose reporter you can use on any list of numbers:

```
to-report rank [items]
  let sorted sort items
  let ranked map [ n -> position n sorted ] items
  report ranked
end

to test-rank
  show rank [5 1 6 7 9] ; outputs [1 0 2 3 4]
  show rank [ 10 9 3 2 10 9 3 2 11 ] ; outputs [6 4 2 0 6 4 2 0 8]
end
```